# How to draw a string on a picturebox with C# immediately after I show it?

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have a main windows form called `Menu.cs`, in this class I have two buttons called 'lines' and 'polygons', each button open its respective window. Polygons got a picturebox and I have to draw the x and y axis

```
private void botonPoligonos_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    WindowPolygons objPolygons = new WindowPolygons();
    objPolygons.Show();
}
```

I actually do it with a button called 'drawAxes':

```
public void drawAxes_Click() 
{
    drawAxes();
}

public void drawAxes()
{
    Graphics papel = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    Pen lapiz = new Pen(Color.Black);
    //Dibujo de ejes X y Y
    papel.DrawLine(lapiz, 20, 425, 742, 425);
    papel.DrawLine(lapiz, 20, 425, 20, 20);
    papel.DrawString("X", myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(745, 418));
    papel.DrawString("Y", myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(14, 5));
}
```

But I don't want to do it with a button, I'd like to draw the axes since the picturebox is shown, I already tried to put the method `drawAxes()` in the constructor, in the loader of `WindowPolygons.cs` and under `objPolygons.show()` but nothing happens, do anyone know how to do it?

This is my first time making a question, thanks:)

Comment: Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : 

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter.. Here the `pBox.Paint` event plus `pbox.Invalidate()` is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code and the following setup:

```
private void drawAxes(Graphics g, Rectangle rect)
{
    Pen lapiz = new Pen(Color.Black);
    //Dibujo de ejes X y Y
    g.DrawLine(lapiz, 20, rect.Height - 20, rect.Width - 20, rect.Height - 20);
    g.DrawLine(lapiz, 20, rect.Height - 20, 20, 20);
    g.DrawString("X", Font, Brushes.Black, new Point(rect.Width - 17 , rect.Height - 27));
    g.DrawString("Y", Font, Brushes.Black, new Point(14, 5));
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    drawAxes(e.Graphics, pictureBox1.Bounds);
}

private void pictureBox1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Have the pictureBox1 docked to the form (property `Dock` set to `Fill`), so that it automatically grows with the form.

Attach the method `pictureBox1_Paint` to the Paint-Event of pictureBox1.

Attach the method `pictureBox1_Resize` to the Resize-Event of pictureBox1.

The call to `Invalidate()` in `pictureBox1_Resize()` asks the pictureBox1 to repaint it when its size has changed.

The method `pictureBox1_Paint()` is automatically called when the picture box needs to be drawn, either because for initial display or because the size has changed or anything else. It calls `drawAxes` to do the actual drawing, passing along the Graphics object to draw on and the current size of the picture box.

Answer (score -2):

In the constructor or form load, the form still not have been painted. So put the method on form paint event of element:

```
protected void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
   Graphics papel = e.Graphics();
   Pen lapiz = new Pen(Color.Black);
   //Dibujo de ejes X y Y
   papel.DrawLine(lapiz, 20, 425, 742, 425);
   papel.DrawLine(lapiz, 20, 425, 20, 20);
   papel.DrawString("X", myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(745, 418));
   papel.DrawString("Y", myFont, Brushes.Black, new Point(14, 5));
}
```

Comment: I did not attend to code because you said this works by button click.